# A Pythonic way to change how an asyncio task should be cancelled from where cancel() is called

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How to change the behavior of a task cancellation from where the task is being cancelled?

What I would dream of:

```py
task = ensure_future(foo())

def foo_done(task)
    try:
        return task.get_result()
    except CancelError as e:
        when, why = e.args
        if when == "now"
            # do something...
        elif when == "asap":
            # do something else...
        else:
            # do default
        print(f"task cancelled because {why}")

task.add_done_callback(foo_done)

[...]

task.cancel("now", "This is an order!")
```

I could attach an object to the task before calling `task.cancel()`, and inspect it later.

```py
task = ensure_future(foo())

def foo_done(task)
    try:
        return task.get_result()
    except CancelError as e:
        when = getattr(task, "_when", "")
        why = getattr(task, "_why", "")
        if when == "now"
            # do something...
        elif when == "asap":
            # do something else...
        else:
            # do default
        print(f"task cancelled because {why}")

task.add_done_callback(foo_done)

[...]
task._when = "now"
task._why = "This is an order!"
task.cancel()
```

But it looks clunky in some situation, when I want to capture the `CancelError` within the task being process for example:

```py
async def foo():
   # some stuff
   try:
       # some other stuff
   except CancellError as e:
       # here I have easily access to the error, but not the task :(
   [...]
```

I'm looking for a more Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: how "now" is different from "asap" taking into account that `foo_done` is a synchronous function.

Comment: I realize that "now" and "asap" was poor examples of I wanted. what i meant is give to the task the reason of the cancellation, and execute some code according to it: if reason = A do this, if reason = B, do that, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution to decorate the `Task` with data relevant for your exception is in fact a good one. Within the task you can access the task being processed with `asyncio.Task.current_task()`.

You could also achieve the syntax you dream of using the following decorator (untested):

```
def propagate_when(fn):
    async def wrapped(*args, **kwds):
        try:
            return await fn(*args, **kwds)
        except CancelledError as e:
            e.when = getattr(asyncio.Task.current_task(), '_when', None)
            raise
    return wrapped
```

Decorating a coroutine with `@propagate_when` allows the code in `foo_done` to access `e.when` when handling `CancelledError`. The downside is that `e.when` will *not* be available inside the task - there you'd still have to use `current_task()`. Because of that inconsistency I would recommend sticking to reading from the task object.

Several related recommendations:

- Put the cancellation code in a utility function that stores the object you pass it and then calls `task.cancel()`. This thin layer of encapsulation should remove the "clunky" feel from the current code.
- Use prefixed attribute names - short and generic ones like `_when` can cause a clash in a future release. (I understand it was just an example, but unprefixed names are always in danger of clashing.)
- Decorate the task with a single object, putting actual data in its attributes. It makes the retrieval simpler and cleaner, and the gives you the option of implementing methods on the stored object.

Comment: thanks! what i was looking for was indeed `asyncio.Task.current_task()`